# Summing specific elements in AMPL

Tags: ampl

Hello fellow optimizers

I'm intending to add a constraint which prohibits the flow between two specific cities to be too high.

I'm intending to this using the following in the .mod file:

```
 set N:= Kiruna Stockholm Boliden;
 var x{N,N} binary;

 minimize sum{i in N, j in N} x[i,j];

 subject to Constraint1:
      sum{i in N, j in N} x[Kiruna, Stockholm] <= 4;
```

However this gives me errors. How to do I properly conduct this summarization?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several errors in the code:

1. You use the data syntax to initialize set `N` in the model. You should either separate the declaration of set `N` and setting data for it or initialize it using the model syntax:

   ```
   set N:= {'Kiruna', 'Stockholm', 'Boliden'};
   ```
2. `minimize` should be followed by the objective name and a colon:

   ```
   minimize obj: sum{i in N, j in N} x[i,j];
   ```
3. Strings `Kiruna` and `Stockholm` should be quoted:

   ```
   x['Kiruna', 'Stockholm'] <= 4;
   ```
4. If `x[i, j]` represents a flow between cities `i` and `j` and you want it not to exceed 4, then you need a collection of constraints instead of summation:

   ```
   subject to Constraint1{i in N, j in N}: x[i, j] <= 4;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I fully understand point 1 through 3. Sorry for not being so understandable - the variables x[i,j] represents a flow which is 1 if the flow from i to j is used in the model or otherwise 0. I wanted to add a summation to declare that the _total_ amount of times a predefined origin and destination route has been undertaken must not exceed a value. Perhaps I should avoid using a summation for this purpose? Do you know any way around using the summation in that place?

Comment: @GustavDanell Sorry, I didn't notice that the variables are binary. In this case the constraint in item 4 is redundant of course. I'm not sure how you represent the routes from i to j in your model though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Im using 
set N = {'K1', 'K2','K3','K4'};
set V = {i in N, j in N: i != j};
to define the sets, and var x{V,V} binary; to define the variable.

Comment: If x is binary, what do you want to limit? The sum over all possible paths between i and j containing only edges (k,l) where x[k,l] != 0?

Comment: I want to restrain the path. For instance, it should not be possible to take the route x['Stockholm', 'Boliden'] no more than for instance 5 times. I'm thinking of Stockholm having a specific product which can only be attained from Stockholm, which in turn only Boliden has a demand for. So in practice, if one take the route Stockholm to Boliden at least four times, it is guaranteed that the demand has been fulfilled. This is what I want to model, the _total_ amount of times some specific routes has been taken.

Comment: I've solved this issue now thanks to your input! Basically I added another index which I could sum over, making the constraint "for all i in V and for all i in J". Many more constraints, but the problem still only takes 15 seconds so. But without your help I wouldnt have done it